# creating an auto installer in ubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt5, eigen3

I am trying to install and run this software https://github.com/mit-biomimetics/Cheetah-Software 
it's for a project but it can t compile for missing dependancies (eigen3).

I would like to create an auto install script to run it.

I have already do the most but i think i have problems in linking path in cmake and qt5.10 and eigen...

The autoinstall.sh code:

Install dependancies

```
sudo apt install mesa-common-dev freeglut3-dev coinor-libipopt-dev libblas-dev liblapack-dev gfortran liblapack-dev coinor-libipopt-dev cmake gcc build-essential libglib2.0-dev default-jdk python-all-dev liblua5.1-dev golang doxygen python-epydoc
```

Clone  MIT Minicheetah software

```
git clone https://github.com/mit-biomimetics/Cheetah-Software.git
cd Cheetah-Software
```

Eigen library

```
wget https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/archive/3.3.7/eigen-3.3.7.zip
unzip eigen-3.3.7.zip
```

lcm library

```
wget https://github.com/lcm-proj/lcm/releases/download/v1.4.0/lcm-1.4.0.zip
unzip lcm-1.4.0.zip
cd lcm-1.4.0

mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
cd ..
cd ..
```

Qt

```
wget http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/qt.io/archive/qt/5.10/5.10.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.10.0.run
chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.10.0.run
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.10.0.run
```

build

```
cd scripts # for now, you must actually go into this folder
./make_types.sh # you may see an error like `rm: cannot remove...` but this is okay
cd ..
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. # there are still some warnings here
make -j
```

Comment: what is your problem??

Comment: hello i am trying to create an auto launch script to run the mini cheetah software simulation; but i have error of include especially with eigen3....

Comment: i posted an issue on the repertory if you can check ? https://github.com/mit-biomimetics/Cheetah-Software/issues/25

Comment: It's great that you have published an issue but SO is independent of GH, so you should show the error message in your question indicating which command line is being generated. Please read [ask] and review the [tour].

Comment: What version of ubuntu do you use?

Comment: 18.04 lts bionic beaver

Comment: yes i think i could make a better post but sorry it is my first ...

Answer (score 0):

1. configure or setup.py or anything relqted in INSTALL or README.MD ( mandatory )
2. make
3. make install

but really you did not choose the most straitforward job, even as a developper I've been surprised many times when using cloned sources.
You should give a try to precompiled ROS for your robots or any distribution that let you install from binary yet you can still cross-compile when dev is done.

Comment: Basically it is another linux distribution. But we usually prefers to develop on a potent machine using VM and emulators then recompile for ROS or anything else.

Comment: Concerning your Qt I would have cloned the Git repository

Comment: ok i posted an issue on the github repertory i hope there it will be an answer...

Comment: https://github.com/mit-biomimetics/Cheetah-Software/issues/25

Answer (score 0):

So i was able to compile and run it after several research and asking forums, it was a problem of compatibility with lcm library and openjdk, so download oracle jdk, do some linking manually and it was all good, absolutely no error in compilation.

Cheetah-Sofware-Ubuntu 18.04-AutoInstall.sh :

https://github.com/STRATOS-ROBOTICS/LeopardMK1/blob/master/install.sh